# checkbox header with row click event is not working properly in extjs 6.5.1

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6-classic

I am using a grid with multiple rows each row having checkbox . If you selectAll by clicking header checkbox , and deselect by clicking any row ,header checkbox is also getting deselected . 
This works as expected in **version 6.0.1** Classical tool kit . Fiddle example is given bellow

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/24tc

but same code does not work in **ext 6.5.1** , if you select all by header checkbox , and deselect any row header checkbox is not getting deselected for first time . Fiddle is given bellow

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/24tf

i need to use row click in checkbox model with header checkbox . please suggest me what to do

Comment: I don't really understand your code. Why are you setting `checkOnly: true` when you're essentially mimicking the behaviour of `checkOnly: false`.

Comment: Hi evan , i do not want to deselect all rows when deselect any row that's why i am using `checkOnly: true` property , and my other confusion is why its having two different behavior in two different versions with same code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i need to use row click in checkbox model with header checkbox . please suggest me what to do

No need to use row click.

I have changed in **selModel** and no need to row click for selection of checkbox. **ExtJs** direct property to check checkbox on row click or checkbox click.

You can check here with working [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/24u1) demo.

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data: [{
        name: 'Lisa',
        email: 'lisa@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-111-1224'
    }, {
        name: 'Bart',
        email: 'bart@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-222-1234'
    }, {
        name: 'Homer',
        email: 'homer@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-222-1244'
    }, {
        name: 'Marge',
        email: 'marge@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-222-1254'
    }]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: store,
    columns: [{
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name'
    }, {
        text: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        text: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone'
    }],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    selModel: {
        checkOnly: false,
        injectCheckbox: 'last',
        mode: 'SIMPLE'
    },
    selType: 'checkboxmodel'
});
```